# Set the title of an uiapp on appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Tell me please, what's wrong with my Google-script...
I've got an app that does some stuff with my data on a spreadsheet. For that purposes Iэму got two user dialogs. It's all ok with the first one but why cant I acces the second one?
Here is the code:

```
function submitMakeBudget(e) {

  var fileName=e.parameter.fileName;
  var sheetName=e.parameter.sheetName;
  var folderId=e.parameter.folderId;
  var comissionMethod=e.parameter.comissionMethod;
  var comissionPercent=e.parameter.comissionPercent;

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();


  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var preloader = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(250).setWidth(200);
  doc.show(preloader);

  // here nothing happens
  preloader.addTitle('awsome title')
```

why is that so?..

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
preloader.addTitle('awsome title')
doc.show(preloader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, you are doing the wrong thing. And also, it's not `addTitle`, it's `setTitle("Your Title Here")`;
The way you are doing it's not right. You can do it in following way.

```
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var preloader = UiApp.createApplication(); //remove .setHeight(250).setWidth(200) from here
preloader.setHeight(250).setWidth(200);

preloader.setTitle("Add your title here");
doc.show(preloader);
```